# get current logged In wordpress user ID in a MySQL View

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have created a MySQL view of a datatable using phpMyAdmin to get round a restriction in the GROUP BY functionality, I need to retrieve data only for the current logged in wordpress user ID. I store the wordpress user ID in dm_holdings.user_id, so I need to match this with say CURRENT_LOGGED_IN_WP_USER_ID in the query shown below.

Is it possible to get that value in a MySQL View, it has to be a MySQL view as opposed to a PHP script, as the datatables server file reads the MySQL View, shown below

```
Editor::inst( $db, 'dm_holdings' )
    ->readTable('v_holdings_by_share') // The VIEW to read data from
    ->field(
        Field::inst( 'id' )->set( false ),
...
```

An extract of the MySQL query is shown below, where CURRENT_LOGGED_IN_WP_USER_ID represents the Wordpress User ID

```
SELECT 
dm_holdings.code AS code,
dm_holdings.name AS name,
SUM(dm_holdings.amount) AS amount        
        FROM
        dm_holdings
        
        WHERE
        dm_holdings.user_id = CURRENT_LOGGED_IN_WP_USER_ID
        GROUP BY
        dm_holdings.code
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Colin

Many Thanks

Colin

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the MySQL query on the view to query a sub query and perform a further grouping which has negated the need for the wordpress user id within MySQL, so I no longer need the information as I have a work around.

Many Thanks

Colin